# Removing all conventions.Will this resolve my problem

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Using  codefirst with an existing database can be quite a challenge as things dont match up the conventions.Still dont know what all conventions are but there you go..

Now if I were to remove all conventions do I still need to do the mapping of fks and many to many etc...

Are there any problems in doing so.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove all conventions you will have to map almost everything with fluent API. Any automatic detection like foreign keys, primary keys etc. is done by conventions. Also translation of data annotation attributes into mapping is done by conventions.

Comment: thanks for your answer and time.My personal view is that even though code first is intended where you dont have a database,the reality is that most of the time there is already a db in place.I just wish more was done to create the plumbing mapping that is required when a db is already in place without going dbfirst all the way.

Comment: The problem is that whole intention of DbContext API was to support code-first. It wasn't supposed to be used with existing database without EDMX. People are doing it because it partially works but it is not supposed usage.